# Convert varchar to date with malformed values in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This whole date code is beyond my understanding but non the less I need to convert a column in a query result from `varchar` to `date`. I have some malformed values and I'm trying to filter them out.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
SET LANGUAGE us_english

select convert(datetime, some_date, 103) 
from   some_table 
where  isdate(some_date) = 1
```

I keep getting

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

When querying for the malformed values I get these two records

```
some_date 
---------
621
232
```

Is there any way to validate the format using `isdate` ?

Thanks, Frustrated Oracle DBA.

**EDIT**

Tried @Sean Lange suggestions and indeed it looked promising

```
select convert(datetime, some_date, 103)
from ( select * from some_table where isdate(some_date) = 1 )
```

But then I added a `where` clause

```
select convert(datetime, some_date, 103)
from ( select * from some_table where isdate(some_date) = 1 ) 
where convert(datetime, some_date ,103) between 
       convert(datetime, '01/07/2014') 
       and convert(datetime,'31/07/2014')
```

How does a where clause being executed before the from?

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that a valid date looks like dd/mm/yyyy how about a simple structure test?

```
select convert(datetime, some_date, 103) 
from some_table
where len(some_date) = 10 --must have exactly the expected number of characters
```

This could be expanded upon (depending on requirements)

```
  and some_date like '__/__/____'
```

Or maybe

```
  and some_date like '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Anything better would probably need you to put together a custom function that does the CONVERT in a try block, returning NULL in the catch block if its an invalid record.  Depends on your requirements...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening and will continue to happen because you can't be certain which order the sql engine will take here. One time it might filter the rows first and another time it does the conversion. So what you need to do is force the order the engine works. We can do this by using a CTE to get only the rows we want to convert.

```
with MyCTE as
(
    select some_date
    from some_table
    where ISDATE(some_date) = 1
)

select CONVERT(datetime, some_date, 103)
from MyCTE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're positive that these are the only malformed values and all malformed values will look like this, you could just go ahead and use a hackish CASE statement

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LEN(datetime) > 3 THEN convert(datetime, some_date, 103) ELSE NULL),
...
```

It's really not elegant, but datetimes are notoriously difficult to make elegant because there are so many fragmented formats. If possible, it saves more headaches just to make sure that your data is correctly formatted in the first place through form validation and regex stuff, but since that's not always possible, we have crummy hacks like this to patch ourselves through. Best of luck!